# Insert form alert sweet doesn't show

Tags: php

I want to:

1. Fill in the box
2. Press the submit button
3. Required check `yes` or `no`
4. If `no`, show alert sweet `sweetAlert("Oops...", "Something went wrong!", "error");`, if `yes` show alert `swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success")`
5. Save text in SQL -> reload home page

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>alert sweet send form</title>
    <script src="sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sweetalert.css">
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="username" required placeholder="userName">
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="password" required placeholder="passWord">
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="validation();">Đăng nhập</button>

<script src="sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validation() {
    var userName = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var passWord = document.getElementById('password').value;
    if ((username == userName) && (password == passWord)) {
        swal({
            title: "Bạn Đăng Nhập Thành Công!",
            timer: 4000,
            showConfirmButton: false
        });
    } else {
        sweetAlert("Lỗi...", "Mật khẩu hoặc tài khoản không đúng!", "error");
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you function must be like this

```
function validation()
{
    var userName    =   document.getElementById('username').value;
    var passWord    =   document.getElementById('password').value;
    swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "your message",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes",
            cancelButtonText: "No",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            closeOnCancel: false
        },
        function(isConfirm){
            if (isConfirm) {
                swal("Good job!!", "You clicked the button!", "success");
                // place your code here
            } else {
                swal("Oops...", "Something went wrong!", "error");
            }
        });
}
```

2. remove action="index.php" from your form

Comment: Thank you for your help. I still can not make it work according to the above rules

Comment: i don't understand you !

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//ket nối
    include 'database.php';
//Hiển thị



        if(isset($_POST['save'])){
        $id= $_POST['id'];
        $username= $_POST['username'];
        $password= $_POST['password'];



$sql="insert into `members`(id,username,password) Values ('$id','$username','$password')";
    // mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");



    $pdo->exec($sql);
//echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Xin chúc mừng, tài khoản được tạo thành công !");window.location ="http://localhost/"; </script>'; 





                        }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>alert sweet send form</title>
    <script src="sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sweetalert.css">
</head>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" required placeholder="userName">
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="password" name="password" required placeholder="passWord">
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="validation();" name="save">Đăng nhập</button>
</form>
    <script src="sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validation()
{
    var userName    =   document.getElementById('username').value;
    var passWord    =   document.getElementById('password').value;
    swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "your message",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes",
            cancelButtonText: "No",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            closeOnCancel: false
        },
        function(isConfirm){
            if (isConfirm) {
                swal("Good job!!", "You clicked the button!", "success");
                // place your code here
            } else {
                swal("Oops...", "Something went wrong!", "error");
            }
        });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```